# Difference between prisma db push and prisma migrate dev

Tags: prisma

what is the difference between `prisma db push` and `prisma migrate dev` ? When should I use one over the other. Docs say that prisma db push is about schema prototyping only and I don't understand what does that mean.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it explained clearly in the docs https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push#choosing-db-push-or-prisma-migrate

Answer (score 11):

They serve two different environments. The `prisma db push` is **not to be used in your production environment**, as stated in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push)

> `db push`  uses the same engine as Prisma Migrate to synchronize your Prisma schema with your database schema, and is best suited for schema
> prototyping. The `db push` command:
>
> 1. Introspects the database to infer and executes the changes required to
>    make your database schema reflect the state of your Prisma schema.
> 2. By default, after changes have been applied to the database schema,
>    generators are triggered (for example, Prisma Client). You do not need
>    to manually invoke `prisma generate`.
> 3. If `db push` anticipates that the changes could result in data loss, it
>    will:
>
> - Throw an error
> - Require the `--accept-data-loss` option if you still want
>   to make the changes
>
> Note: `db push` does not interact with or rely on
> migrations. The migrations table will not be updated, and no migration
> files will be generated.

The `prisma migrate dev` is used in you local environment, as explained in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate#development-environments)

> `migrate dev` is a development command and should never be used in a
> production environment.
>
> This command:
>
> 1. Replays the existing migration history in the shadow database in order
>    to detect schema drift (edited or deleted migration file, or a manual
>    changes to the database schema)
> 2. Applies pending migrations to the
>    shadow database (for example, new migrations created by colleagues)
> 3. Generates a new migration from any changes you made to the Prisma
>    schema before running `migrate dev`
> 4. Applies all unapplied migrations to
>    the development database and updates the `_prisma_migrations` table
> 5. Triggers the generation of artifacts (for example, the Prisma Client)
>
> The `migrate dev` command will prompt you to reset the database in the
> following scenarios:
>
> - Migration history conflicts caused by modified or missing migrations
> - The database schema has drifted away from the end-state of the
>   migration history

If you have any other question regarding this, there is this comparison in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push#choosing-db-push-or-prisma-migrate) explaining when to use one or the other.

Comment: This is dangerously incorrect. `prisma db push` is never used against a production environment. As stated in the docs it is for local rapid prototyping only. All operations against production environments should be performed by deploying migrations.

Comment: Note that if you are using Prisma with MongoDB you _do_ use `db push` instead of `prisma migrate dev/deploy`. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb#considerations

Comment: Wait, so if `db push` "is not to be used in your production environment", and `migrate dev` "is used in you local environment"... then what am I supposed to use in production?

Comment: @mrodo When it comes to production, you would use `prisma migrate deploy`. More info can be found in [these docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-migrate/understanding-prisma-migrate/mental-model)

Answer (score 5):

- Prisma db push syncs (and formats) your prisma schema to that of your database schema.
- While prisma migrate dev "command automatically generates SQL migration files (saved in /prisma/migrations) and applies them to the database".

The **main difference** between both is the **generation of the migration files**.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> **Use db push to prototype a schema at the start of a project and initialize a migration history when you are happy with the first draft**

> Use db push to prototype a change to an existing schema, then run prisma migrate dev to generate a migration from your changes (you will be asked to reset)

So the key for me here, was that only the first time I had to run db push (into a heroku app with heroku postgres). After that, migrations all the time...

Answer (score 0):

I had changed from **prisma db push** to **prisma migrate dev**
Because prima db push can't allow me to change the column's name to the different one you want.

Example: The table USER has a column employee_name, you want to change it to name. If you use **prisma db push** your data will be lost. You must use **prisma migrate dev** to do this one.